# Windows..h: Thread safety for shared resource between background worker and main

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety, locking

I have a main program thread and a background worker thread which is meant to refill `TokenBucket`s for a ratelimiter. The main thread is the webserver itself.

Anyways, in the main program I create and use multiple structs type `HttpRoute`.

In the ratelimiter thread, the route structs are being accessed and a field (TokenBucket) is being modified in a `while (1)` loop.

**How can I safely use this "route" in the main thread AND background worker thread when main rarely modifies (only during initialization of server) and background worker modifies TokenBucket?**

Code for rate-limiter worker:

```c
int http_refill_token_bucket(node *bucket, int numArgs, ...)
{
    // Extract args
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, numArgs);

    int max_requests = va_arg(args, int);
    int seconds = va_arg(args, int);

    HttpTokenBucket *b = (HttpTokenBucket*)bucket->value;

    // Calculate the number of seconds since the last refill
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    int seconds_since_refill = now - b->last_refill;

    int tokens_to_add = seconds_since_refill * (max_requests / seconds);

    b->tokens += tokens_to_add;

    if (b->tokens > b->max_tokens)
    {
        va_end(args);
        return - 1;
    }

    b->last_refill = now;

    va_end(args);
    return b->tokens;
}


int http_refill_token_buckets(HttpRoute *route)
{
    // Iterates all the IP address buckets
    int res = ht_iter(route->token_buckets, http_refill_token_bucket, 2, route->max_requests, route->seconds);
}

DWORD WINAPI http_rate_limit_worker(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    // Cast the parameter to the correct type
    HttpRateLimitWorkerArgs *args = (HttpRateLimitWorkerArgs*)lpParam;
    HttpServer *server = args->server;

    // After unpacking, free the args
    http_rate_limit_worker_args_destroy(args);

    while (1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            tree* method_routes = server->method_routes[i];
            
            // Iterate over the routes
            tree_iter(method_routes, http_refill_token_buckets, http_route_compare);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: If one thread modifies a resource at the same time while another thread may read it, you should synchronize these events. You could use a mutex for this.

Comment: Generally, the simplest way to synchronize two threads accessing a shared object is to use a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)). On Microsoft Windows, the simplest form of a mutex, which can only be used by threads inside the same process (which is sufficient in your case), is a so-called [Critical Section Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/critical-section-objects).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I mean, if the server get's a LOT of requests, the request handler might +1 token while the ratelimit thread tries to refill, so both could happend to write at same time.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have read about slim Read Write locks too, but I don't see how that might me useful in this case. Could maybe you fill me in on why I should use a mutex > SRW lock

Comment: @MagnusEnebakk You use a mutex to synchronize the events as I mentioned. That is to get a program with defined behavior. If you don't, you'll have race conditions and undefined behavior - which is a nightmare. Such program may look like they are working and then suddenly they don't.

Comment: @MagnusEnebakk: I believe SRW locks are mainly useful if you have several threads attempting to read from the shared object and if writes are only seldom. The advantage of SRW locks is that they allow more than one thread to read from the shared object at once, as long as no thread is attempting to write to the shared object. However, if I understand your question properly, you have one writer thread and one read/write thread. Therefore, I do not see any advantage in having SRW locks compared to a standard Critical Section Object, because you will never have two read-only threads.

Comment: Anyway, it's in the scope of [Synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization). The important point is to synchronize access to a resource.